# Empty markdown diffs do not show difference

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

Sometimes, there are empty diffs for review, like [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1718777). I believe**d** they represent nothing, <s>thus can be discarded</s>. Edit: Actually, the markdown does not show the difference.

[image: Two empty diffs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my [Markdown diff engine changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258959/115866) was that you can see these things better now:

[image: screenshot of the diff after the fix]

(click to enlarge). It's still somewhat subtle (I don't want to add visible characters for newlines, that creates way too much noise), but you can see the difference now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [rendered output](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1718777), you will see that the editor added carriage returns after the curly braces.

Comment: True! Can you see a difference in the markdown, though?

Comment: @false No, they look identical.